# Code to validate an email address always fails

Tags: php, mysql, url, url-shortener

I have edited some code I found on 'ye old internet (http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/using-htaccess-files-for-pretty-urls/). I have not gotten my variation of the code to work properly. My edited versions requests another input called "pages" from index.php. Pages is put into the database along with $url and $short. Pages goes into a pages field in the database which has a varchar value. Pages is later called in serve.php for a javascript purpose. In the code below I have noted where I think the problem occurs. If your interested in my faulty code, stay tuned; I have yet to edit the other files.

I am starting to think the error could be happening in MYSQL because I almost always receive the first $html error of "Error: invalid url"

```
<?php  
  require("./db_config.php");  
  $url = $_REQUEST['url'];
  $pages = $_REQUEST['pages'];  
  //this seems to be where the errors are occuring
  if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]+[:\/\/]+[A-Za-z0-9\-_]+\\.+[A-Za-z0-9\.\/%&=\?\-_]+$/i",     $url)) {  
    $html = "Error: invalid URL";  
  } else {  

    $db = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password);  

      $short = substr(md5(time().$url), 0, 5);  

      if(mysql_query("INSERT INTO `".$database."`.`url_redirects` (`short`, `url`,    `pages`) VALUES ('".$short."', '".$url."', '".$pages."');", $db)) {  
        $html = "Your short URL is<br />www.srprsr.com/".$short;  
      } else {  
        $html = "Error: cannot find database";  
      }  

    mysql_close($db);  
  }  
?>
```

Comment: Long codes, long question. What is the value of `$pages` before checking `preg_match` ?

Comment: Before that I'd like to know the value of `$url`.

Answer (score 0):

Consider `filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)` instead of a regular expression.

http://php.net/filter.examples.validation
http://php.net/filter.filters.validate